# why so many errors are occuring in building the addon?

Tags: g1ant

[I am unable to resolve these errors and also can't understand their cause.Can anybody help?I have also refreshed dependencies, it is occuring after that too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRqAO.png)

I uninstall and then installed g1ant from manage nutmeg package still I am facing this error.

Comment: Do not  post links to code or errors, put them into the question. also determine what you are asking and trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to uninstall G1ANT robot from manage nutmeg package present under Project as it is old version and then go to browse menu and Search G1ANT there and install it and then try to build your addon.
Hope it works!

Comment: No,  this is not working, errors are occurring after that too. I uninstalled and installed still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to try 2 3 times . I had to re-install g1ant language package 2 times to stop receiving those errors.
Also you can check reference to verify that whether g1ant language is un-installed and then re-install it.